# DevExpress Export ASPxGridView when a ribbon button item is clicked

Tags: c#, javascript, devexpress, export-to-excel, ribbon

I am trying to export my grid view when I click on a ribbon button

The problem is tha the ribbon button click is a client side event and  the export function is handled by the server.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //Ribbon events
    function onCommandExecuted(s, e) {
        var name = e.item.name;
        if (name == "Ajouter") {
            grid.AddNewRow();
        }

        else if (name == "Modifier") {
            grid.StartEditRow(grid.GetFocusedRowIndex());
        }
        else if (name == "Supprimer") {
            if (confirm("Vous confirmez la suppression de l'élement selectionné ?")) {
                grid.DeleteRow(grid.GetFocusedRowIndex());
            }
        }
        else if (name = "Excel")
        {
           //What to do here?
        }
    }


</script>
  //The export function (C#)
  protected void btnXlsExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gridExport.WriteXlsToResponse();
}
```

How do I call the export function in my script.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned before you can export GridView only from server site after postback. You can add near your gridview hidden control, something like from code below

```
<dx:ASPxButton runat="server" ID="_exportBtn" ClientInstanceName="_exportBtn" ClientVisible="false" OnClick="OnClickExport" />
```

move the unloading code to the OnClickExport method

```
    public void OnClickExport(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        gridExport.WriteXlsxToResponse();
    }
```

and then click on it from you client side code

```
    else if (name = "Excel")
    {
       //What to do here?
       _exportBtn.OnClick();
    }
```

Comment: Then, please, mark this post as an answer to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

> [ASPxGridView](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridViewMembersTopicAll) does not allow to export its content on the client
>   side. You can accomplish this task only on the server side. This task
>   can be accomplish only on the server side via postback.

Refer:
[How to export ASPxGridView content on the client side](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q517561)
[ASPxGridView - How to export the grid on the client side](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q396533)

See Also:
[Exporting Data - Exporting to PDF, XLS, XLSX and RTF](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/Exporting/Exporting.aspx)

**Edit:**
Source: [ASPxGridView - How to export ASPxGridView via a callback](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q422711)

It is impossible to export and download files when processing a callback due to the callback design: The Concept of Callbacks. To overcome this, send a full postback via [ASPxButton](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxEditorsASPxButtontopic). In this case, you will be able to export grid data in the [ASPxButton.Click](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsASPxButton_Clicktopic) event handler. Please note that you need to bind ASPxGridView to a corresponding datasource that depends on the active tab of your ASPxtabControl.

Example:
// Buttton Markup

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="btnXlsExport" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False"  ClientInstanceName="btnXlsExport" UseSubmitBehavior="true"                         OnClick="btnXlsExport_Click" Text="Export">
</dx:ASPxButton>
```

// Call it direct within your javascript code using [ASPxClientButton.DoClick Method](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsScriptsASPxClientButton_DoClicktopic)

```
else if (name = "Excel")
{
  btnXlsExport.DoClick();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in that case I wonder if I can call a code behind function when a ribbon button item is clicked 
             
        <ClientSideEvents CommandExecuted="onCommandExecuted"/> // onCommandExecuted is a code behind function

?